# Is it possible to make strong reference cycles using SwiftData?

Tags: swift, model, swift-data

Almost on all tutorials I have seen of SwiftData they relate @Models between each others.
Is it possible to make strong reference cycles using SwiftData? Or is it enough by marking them as @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) or nullify?

Example.

```
@Model
class Country {
 var name: String
 var states: [State]

 init(...)...
} 

@Model
class State {
 var name: String
 var country: Country

 init(...)...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models don't store the relationships by themselves, behind the scenes the storage is resolved by the `ModelContext`. Thus, even circular relationships are safe from this point of view (retain cycles).

`@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)` is needed only if your database rules require the related models to also be deleted.

Comment: To expand on your answer the secret here lies in how the `@Model` macro influences the properties within the model. If you expand that you'll see you properties are themselves wrapped in yet more macros such as `@_PersistedProperty`. There you'll see custom `get` and `set` which I'm guessing is where the magic happens